# removeObserver on one class, will remove all observers for the same keypath on all classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

I have this code on a lot of classes:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] addObserver:self
                                        forKeyPath:CAR_MODE
                                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                           context:NULL];
```

And on each class I add this on each dealloc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

My question is: **Do I have to removeObserver on each class?**

If I am 'observing' `CAR_MODE` on classes instances `Class1` and `Class2`, if I remove observer for `CAR_MODE` on `Class1`, do I will remove 'observing' on `Class2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I assume that for "class" you mean "class instance" or "object":

> If I am 'observing' CAR_MODE on classes Class1 and Class2, if I remove observer for CAR_MODE on Class1, do I will remove 'observing' on Class2?

No, every object has it's own observer, so if you remove it on "ClassInstance1" it will not be removed on "ClassInstance2".